# EJS function parameter is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have 50 different image inputs and I dont want to write them all, so
I want to use a function where I can set the parameters and only have to call the func with the parameters. Inside the ejs (html) I want to set the name attribut like this `name="<% name2 %>"` but if I call the func with value painting3 for name it throws

> 58|     <% callPainting(post.paintings, paintings3, ) %>
>
> paintings3 is not defined

I defined post in app.js

```
router.get('/:id/edit', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const findPost = await Post.findById(req.params.id)
        res.render('admin/edit', {
            layout: 'layouts/admin',
            post: findPost,

        })
    } catch {
        res.redirect('/admin')
    }
})
```

and every input should looks like this `<input type="file" class="filepond" name="paintings2" value="<%= post.paintings2 %>">`
So i did this, but its not working as I expected

```
<% function callPainting(postimage, postname, postdate, postprice, checkImage, postshowImage, name, name2, date, price, showImage) { %>
        <input type="file" class="filepond" name="<% name %>" value="<%= postimage %>">
<% } %>
```

I got some more parameters but thats the same problem